# HTML - form input

Tags: html, forms

I need some simple quick help,

Here's my form that i want to edit:

```
<div class="form_radio">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <br />
        <form name="gender-male-female">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" id="m">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" id="f">Female
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working example:

```
<div class="form_password">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Create a password</label>
        <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Create a password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put :

> id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')"

into the radio group but I dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code and let me know. Hope it will help for you.

```
<form name="myForm">
        <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="m" id="m" /> Male 
        <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="f" id="f"/> Female
</form>

<script>
var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
var prev = null;
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
  rad[i].onclick = function() {
    (prev)? console.log(prev.value):null;
    if(this !== prev) {
        prev = this;
    }
    console.log(this.value)
  };
}
</script>
```

**OR**

For client-side validation, here's some Javascript to check which one is selected:

```
if(document.getElementById('m').checked) {
   //Male radio button is checked
}else if(document.getElementById('f').checked) {
   //Female radio button is checked
}
```